# Amazon-appstore rejected Flutter app due to not installing on android virtual device 4.0

Tags: android, flutter, amazon-appstore

Amazon app store app rejected my app publishing because it is not installing on android virtual device 4.0
I need some help I am new on amazon app store, same app is running on play store and ios app store.
What should I do and how should I test, any help will be appreciated.

issue screenshot -
[image: issue]

below is my APK file screenshot -
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got the issue, we need to add min and max supported sdk versions in the main/AndroidManifest.xml file.
because amazon app store does not get it from build.gradle file.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="29"
        android:maxSdkVersion="29" />
```

[image]